# Ember js -- remove duplicates from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I am trying to clean up a validation script.

So if the file type uploaded is wrong -- like an image instead of a pdf. I need the alert to say -- Wrong file type uploaded, only pdf accepted.

https://jsfiddle.net/mf78otve/37/

so the validation string looks like this

```
"application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf"
```

but really need to clean it up  -- pdf, x-pdf, vnd.pdf, pdf, x-pdf

then remove duplicates to then pdf, x-pdf, vnd.pdf

```
var validations = "application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf";

console.log("validations", validations);

var res = validations.split("/");
console.log("res", res);


var uniqueArray = function(arrArg) {
  return arrArg.filter(function(elem, pos,arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(elem) == pos;
  });
};


console.log(uniqueArray(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set`, `split`, `filter` and `map`

```
var output = [...new Set( //Use set to remove duplicates
     input.split(",") //split by comma
          .map(s => s.split("/")[1]) take out value after /
          .filter( s => s.includes( "pdf" ) ) //only keep the values having pdf in it
)];
```

**Demo**

```js
var input = "application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf";

var output = [...new Set(input.split(",").map(s => s.split("/")[1]).filter( s => s.includes( "pdf" ) ))];

console.log( output )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `split` then `map` and finllay `filter`

```js
var validations = "application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf";

var result = validations.split`, `.map((a)=>a.split`/`[1]).filter((a,p,s)=>a.includes`pdf`&& s.indexOf(a)==p)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: -- could we split this further -- split(".")  -- split ("-")  -- to try and remove further duplicates?

Comment: @TheOldCounty sure

Comment: also needs to check for ppt  -- application/ppt, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint -- but this includes = pdf only

Comment: var validations = "application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, application/ppt, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";

var result = validations.split(', ').map((a)=>a.split('/')[1])
.filter((a,p,s)=>a.includes`pdf`||  a.includes`ppt` && s.indexOf(a)==p)

console.log(result)